# .net core api with identityserver4 in one project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I am trying to achieve in one project lets called it TablesReachApi to have identityserver (LoaclAuthentication) and swagger definition.

I added some test UserController, and implemented swashbuckle, thats ok, but Im having a problem to setup swagger authorization as well as getting token from authority.

here is the code:
[Code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/64R7M5yZcf/)

When I try to call `http://localhost:5001/connect/token` with autorization username and password:
client:secret, and in body Ive checked `x-www-form-urlencoded` -> grant_type: client_credentials, scope: TablesReachApi Im getting error: invalid_scope

Here is my code [repo](https://github.com/stefancvetkovic/TablesReach)

Comment: I just quickly scanned your code, it seems that API resource is missing(`aud` property of token). To fix this can you try doing these: 1. Set scopes of `ApiResource` 2.Add the api resources on `AddIdentityServer`

Comment: but I added already. please see my github repo. thanks

Comment: NOTE your repo sends a 404 code - cant find such page.

Comment: sorry, please try again, thanks

Comment: Set`Scopes` property of `new ApiResource(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)`  to your scopes

Comment: still nothing. I renamed `TablesReachApi` string to `IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName` and in my postman Im calling string `"dentityServerApi"` (IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName) https://i.imgur.com/1wgkuAy.png

Comment: added the answer as its really hard to post code on comment

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly scanned your code, it seems that API resource/scope is missing(aud property of token). To fix this can you try doing these:

1. Set scopes property of `ApiResource`:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
   new ApiScope[]
   { 
      new ApiScope("TablesReachApi")
   };

public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
   new ApiResource[]
   {
      new ApiResource("IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName")
    {
       Scopes = new []{ "TablesReachApi" }
    },
   };
```

2. Add the api scopes on AddIdentityServer by calling `AddInMemoryApiScopes`

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
            .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);
```

Comment: Im still getting `error: invalid_scope` https://i.imgur.com/398ivZh.png https://i.imgur.com/DXjPPE3.png I think my call is ok?

Comment: could you update the code, and let me see the code again

Comment: I can see tha changes? https://i.imgur.com/TXPIly6.png Please try again?

Comment: also here it is .well-known configuration from my authotiry identity server https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p6yw8h64BZ/

Comment: `AddInMemoryApiScopes` is still missing

Comment: As you see, your api scope is also missing on `scopes_supported` on .well-known configuration result

Comment: yes, I now retrieved a token, and now I want to call `/api/users` method no params, GET method. Im getting 500 Internal Server Error. I included Bearer token https://i.imgur.com/lsEtNp7.png do I need to pass through authorization again username and password?

Comment: but I for some reason cannot call my method because the user is unauthenticated. `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10204: The user is unauthenticated. The HttpContext does not contain any claims.`

Comment: Your client is authentication using Client Creds grant (`AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials`) which is not on behalf of a user. This grant is for server to server. But on your controller you are trying to list the logged in users which never logged in. I suggest you to change your controller to return a simple string and verify the authorization.

Comment: can you incirorate that part in your answer, to try it and to accept your answer? thanks

Comment: Sure I can do that, but I believe the answer is already the fix for question you posted originally. your current issue is not related with the question posted. I suggest you to ask a new question